Extracting fingerprints out of a photo - line thinning
I am working on a school project for my biometrics class. I am supposed to extract the type of a fingerprint out of a direction field (arch, tended arch, loop, whorl, twin loop) and minutae out of the ridges.
I somehow managed to get the lines out of the sample photo, but despite trying all kinds of filters, the result is still very very noisy and unsuitable to be used for minutae extraction. What I want is some tips regarding the filtering used - I recognized that one of the problems is that the lines are not connected and the presence of noise makes finding real minutae impossible. What I tried were gaussian filters, bilateral filters, gabor filters, all of the sorts. This is the best result I was able to get.
This is my code (a fully working, standalone example). Included in this post is also an example output that showcases the problems that I have. Furthermore, I added the fingerprint photo too at the end of this post (it's a stock photo, I usually use my own fingerprints which I don't really want to post here):
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Hardcoded path to input image
IMAGE_PATH = '20241108_171310.jpg'  # Replace with the path to your image


# Extracts the finger
def crop_image(image):
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # I use skin tone to get the boundaries. There may be better options.
    lower_skin = np.array([0, 0, 80], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_skin = np.array([7, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    lower_skin2 = np.array([170, 0, 80], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_skin2 = np.array([179, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

    skin_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_skin, upper_skin),
                               cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_skin2, upper_skin2))
    skin_mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(skin_mask, (51, 51), 20)
    skin_mask = cv2.inRange(skin_mask, 200, 255)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if not contours:
        return image

    largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    blacked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=skin_mask)

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)
    h = min(int(1.5 * w), h)
    cropped_image = blacked[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    return cropped_image

# Scales to target resolution
def scale_image(image, final_width):
    coefficient = final_width / image.shape[1]
    return cv2.resize(image, (int(image.shape[1] * coefficient), int(image.shape[0] * coefficient)))

# Calculates and draws the direction field out of sobel gradients
def draw_directions(directions, image, tile_size):
    for y in range(directions.shape[0]):
        for x in range(directions.shape[1]):
            cx = x * tile_size + tile_size // 2
            cy = y * tile_size + tile_size // 2
            dir_x, dir_y = np.cos(directions[y, x]), np.sin(directions[y, x])
            magnitude = math.sqrt(dir_x ** 2 + dir_y ** 2)
            dir_x /= magnitude
            dir_y /= magnitude
            line_length = 15
            x_end = cx + int(dir_x * line_length / 2)
            y_end = cy + int(dir_y * line_length / 2)
            x_start = cx - int(dir_x * line_length / 2)
            y_start = cy - int(dir_y * line_length / 2)
            cv2.line(image, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

def get_directions(grad_x, grad_y, image_shape, tile_size):
    directions = np.zeros((image_shape[0] // tile_size, image_shape[1] // tile_size), dtype=np.float32)
    for y in range(image_shape[0] // tile_size):
        for x in range(image_shape[1] // tile_size):
            tile_grad_x = grad_x[y * tile_size:(y + 1) * tile_size, x * tile_size:(x + 1) * tile_size]
            tile_grad_y = grad_y[y * tile_size:(y + 1) * tile_size, x * tile_size:(x + 1) * tile_size]

            a = 2 * np.sum(tile_grad_x * tile_grad_y)
            b = np.sum(tile_grad_x ** 2 - tile_grad_y ** 2)
            directions[y, x] = 0.5 * np.arctan2(a, b) + np.pi / 2

    return directions

def extract_lines(grayscale_image):
    # Enhance contrast
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    enhanced = clahe.apply(grayscale_image)

    # Apply stronger Gaussian blur
    enhanced = cv2.GaussianBlur(enhanced, (5, 5), 3)

    # Adaptive thresholding with adjusted parameters
    thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(enhanced, 255,
                                        cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
                                        31, -2)

    # Morphological operations
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
    thresholded = 255 - cv2.erode(255 - thresholded, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Enhance continuity
    thresholded = enhance_continuity(thresholded)

    return thresholded

def enhance_continuity(binary_image):
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    # Close small gaps
    closed = cv2.morphologyEx(binary_image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    # Remove small noise
    opened = cv2.morphologyEx(closed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    return opened

def thin_lines(binary_image):
    # Ensure ridges are white, valleys are black for thinning operation
    thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(binary_image)
    return thinned

def connect_ridges(thinned_image, max_gap=5):
    result = thinned_image.copy()

    # Find endpoints
    kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                       [1, 10, 1],
                       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)
    conv = cv2.filter2D(result.astype(np.float32), -1, kernel)
    endpoints = np.where((conv == 11) & (result == 255))

    # Connect nearby endpoints
    for i in range(len(endpoints[0])):
        y1, x1 = endpoints[0][i], endpoints[1][i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(endpoints[0])):
            y2, x2 = endpoints[0][j], endpoints[1][j]
            dist = np.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
            if 0 < dist <= max_gap:
                cv2.line(result, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 1)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load image
    image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
    if image is None:
        print(f"Error: Unable to load image at {IMAGE_PATH}")
        exit()

    # Process image
    cropped_image = crop_image(image)
    scaled_image = scale_image(cropped_image, 768)
    grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(scaled_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Enhanced preprocessing
    grayscale_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale_image, (5, 5), 3)

    # Sobel gradients
    sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(grayscale_image, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
    sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(grayscale_image, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)

    # Get and draw directions
    directions = get_directions(sobel_x, sobel_y, grayscale_image.shape, 32)
    image_directions = scaled_image.copy()
    draw_directions(directions, image_directions, 32)

    # Extract and enhance lines
    extracted_lines = extract_lines(grayscale_image)
    enhanced_lines = enhance_continuity(extracted_lines)

    # Thin lines and connect ridges
    thinned_lines = thin_lines(enhanced_lines)
    connected_lines = connect_ridges(thinned_lines, max_gap=30)
    
    
    # So that the first two displayed images are not blue
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cropped_image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Display results
    images = [image, cropped_image, image_directions, 255 - extracted_lines, 255 - enhanced_lines, 255 - thinned_lines, 255 - connected_lines]
    titles = ["Original Image", "Cropped Image", "Orientation Field", "Extracted Lines", "Enhanced Lines", "Thinned Lines", "Connected Lines"]

    plt.figure(figsize=(35, 10))
    for i in range(len(images)):
        plt.subplot(1, 7, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i], cmap='gray' if i > 1 else None)
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()




"type" of fingerprint, that's one quality describing the whole fingerprint, right? but then you talk of minutae, which are local features. -- you might wanna look around for a neural network model that'll do the segmentation. that should have learned to yield the "quality" of segmentation that you're looking for.

@ChristophRackwitz Yes, the project is supposed to describe both the quality of the whole fingerprint and THEN describe the local features. However, we are explicitly not allowed to use neural networks for this, instead, we should rely on classic algorithms. That's why I am doing this.

Since this is a school assignment, presumably the class has covered all the techniques you need for the task.  I tried to solve this problem 38 years ago and failed, but I didn't have training on the classic image processing techniques.  It's a hard problem!

The orientation field you extracted looks pretty good. That is all you need, really. The rest of the processing doesn't get you closer to your goal. The local features of the orientation vector field are what defines the minutiae. Look for example at the divergence and the curl of the vector field.

Im not entirely sure how I would go about this but I feel like the main issue youre running into is that the highlights in the input image are too blown out. I would start by evening out the lighting in the original image before extracting the fingerprints. You could either bring the whites down in brightness or do a more complicated approach with highlights.
You could probably find an open source image editor with that functionality and just copy over what you need into a function in your script then run the rest of your script on the modified image.

Hey and welcome to stackoverflow, in its' current state your answer does not specifically solve the problem. When you gain enough rep, you'll be able to post comments under posts
